# CiviCRM Profile Forms: Label and TextBox on the same line

Tags: profile, forms, css

Need your help....I have a form (created via a profile) which contains textboxes with labels...The default view shows the textboxes below their respective labels...Is it possible to show the textboxes right next to the labels?

Comment: Take a look at one of the Demo sites to see how it comes 'out of the box' in case it is your theme that is breaking what would otherwise look okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some CSS to your theme to do this; use Firefox Firebug / Firefox Developer Edition or Chrome's Developer Tools to inspect the html and find the class you need to edit - to float the elements side by side.